# Write a simple Linux shell in c

Tags: c, linux

I have an assignment, to create a simple linux shell using exec() that runs basic commands (e.g ls, ps) without arguments.  When i run the code the execv is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char argv[100];
char* path= "/bin/";
char progpath[20];

while(1)
{

printf("My shell>> ");
gets(argv);


if(strcmp(argv, "exit\n")==0){
    break;
}
strcpy(progpath, path);
strcat(progpath, argv);

 for(int i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++){
    if(progpath[i]=='\n'){
        progpath[i]='\0';
    }
int pid= fork();

if(pid==0){
    execvp(progpath,argv);
    exit(1);

}else{
    wait(NULL);

}
return 0;

}
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to narrow down where the segfault occurs? Did you intend `argv` to be a single array of characters (one string)? As it's defined, it's an array of *pointers* to character, so it's an array of uninitialized pointers to characters.

Comment: @lurker is right, you must use gdb to find out where your bug is ! 1/ gcc -ggdb -o <your executable> <your source> 2/ ulimit -c unlimited 3/ re-run your binary and trig a segfault 4/ gdb <your executable> <core file> 5/ type "bt" and just find out where your programming error is !

Answer (score 4):

gets(argv) is expecting a char array, not a pointer to a array of char arrays.

change

```
char* argv[100];
```

to

```
char argv[100];
```

And then

```
strcat(progpath, argv[0]);
```

to

```
strcat(progpath, argv);
```

Note also that gets etc, is assuming you are not going to provide too many characters to fit in the array, so if the user enters a value that will be more than the 14 characters then progpath will overflow.

You are missing includes for fork, wait etc - likely to be

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

After that, why `for(int i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++)` and run the execvp each character of the progpath ? I assume you are meaning to have to the closing brackets before then.

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++){
  if(progpath[i]=='\n'){
    progpath[i]='\0';
  }
}

int pid= fork();
```

execva expects an array of char arrays, which is probally why you decided to use char *argv[] originally, but is not valid now - use one of the execl type functions instead.

Lastly, there is a chance that `ls` is a bashonly command - not a real command, so may not work anyway.

use

Comment: I changed argv[0] to argv . Error is now gone but still execv not working

Comment: didnt understand : After that, why for(int i=0; i<strlen(progpath); i++) and run the execvp each character of the progpath ? I assume you are meaning to have to the closing brackets before then.

Comment: **`gets` is dangerous and deprecated.** OP should at least use [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and preferably [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or even [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)

Comment: while I agree, its not the issue why it isn't working

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is declared as an array of unallocated strings and is used as an allocated string. As a first step you should remove the `*` in `char* argv[100];`.

Comment: added additional change